# When to use parallelStream or Thread for processing parallel data in java and Spring

Tags: java-stream, executorservice

I have to process n number of files from a path. Each file has max of 10k records.
I have to take each file and do following process after reading the file content.

1. Check file data is available in a NoSQL DB
2. If any data is available has to update few fields.
3. After update need to call backend REST call to send the updated info to another backend.
4. After this send a notification (Email) using a REST call.

These process should happen in order for each file.

I though of doing this using ExecutorService of Java and Spring so that we can have better control over Exception handling. But my question was is this use case is good to use parallelStream.

Here I think to use of parallelStream after we know the number of files from the path.But is it good idea to use it when we have these many backend calls.

Comment: I don't see any need to reinvent the wheel. There are many frameworks that exist to do exactly this. Spring Integration, Apache Camel, Kafka, Fuse, to name a few.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I am working on existing code in which we don't have Spring integration. I just want to know can we use paralleStream for this kind of use cases/design. As it has different backend calls.

Comment: Probably, but this question is too general for SO. parallelStream simply runs a stream in parallel. However, this doesn't really strike me as a data streaming operation. This is a sequence of actions as in a proceedure or process. These types of things are much better suited to be done under something that manages each step in the process, such as mentioned above. Streaming isn't good for retries and inspection and notifications that are typically needed for a process.